# Linux shell that allows you to choose from tab completion

Tags: shell, autocomplete

This is an odd question, and I don't have a lot of information to provide but .. I recall seeing a Linux terminal that had a feature which allowed its user to choose between the options listed from a tab completion (lets say for a directory listing) by using the arrow keys on the keyboard.

And it also appeared to highlight the options from the tab completion listing as you continued to type.

So, if you tabbed completed in a directory to see the listing of files, the list would show up under where you are working and remain there .. allowing you to continue to type and then that still existent tab completion would start to highly what you have chosen before it disappeared (because you eventually chose one of the listed options)

Does anyone know what terminal this is?

Answer (score 6):

in `zsh` you can select this behaviour (among many others) with:

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*:default' menu select=0
```

which you can put in your `$HOME/.zshrc` file.

NB: this is the behaviour of the shell which is run in the terminal. You can select your shell with the `chsh` command (may depend on the system you're working on, there are many posts here on how to select your shell).

In simple terms, the shell is the program doing something with your inputs and the terminal is the thing which you actually see on your display (and the terminal takes the output from the shell to visualise it and forwards what you type to the shell). There are many terminals (`xterm`, `urxvt`, `xfce4-terminal`, `gnome-terminal`, … ) which can all display shells.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance you're looking for [Fish shell](http://fishshell.com/).

Second possibility I'm aware of is Final Term - [you can see it's demo here](http://worldwidemann.com/final-term-a-modern-terminal-emulator/). Beware, though, as it's development got discontinued.

If you're not looking for terminal, but for some features, like choosing between completion options, you can do it in `bash` using TAB after binding `menu-complete` to it:

```
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
```

To make it permanenent, write that line in `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\t": menu-complete
```

Comment: Yes, it was Fish Shell. THank you so much that answers my question. Out of curiousity, do you know of any downfalls/drawbacks  to using a terminal like fish?

Comment: If I remember correctly (I might be wrong), when I installed it `/bin/sh` got linked to `/bin/fish`. Some things that depended on `/bin/sh` being something else - probably `bash` in `sh` compatibility mode, stopped working. Deinstallation followed, especially as I'm using `bash` and `guake` anyway.

Comment: It looks like ZSH has some of the same features that I was looking for also .. but its referred to as a shell.

Comment: Yes, ZSH has many quality-of-life improvements - but I don't know what's possible without additional packages. Using shell for those features is a nice thing, as it should work with nearly any terminal emulator.

Comment: @Oscalation, fish is a shell like bash or zsh, not a terminal. fish syntax is completely different from the POSIX/Bourne sh syntax, so for it to be installed as sh, something must have gone horribly wrong. zsh, however is Bourne-like and has a sh emulation mode which could in theory allow it to run "sh" (but I'm not aware of any distro that would symlink sh -> zsh)

Comment: I don't fully understand the difference between bash and shell but I'll do some research to try and find out. Seems like learning the different syntax for fish may hurt me because when I'm working on a server at work.. They won't have zsh or fish.

Comment: Excuse me, terminal and shell.